# Which is the best option? Use an unupdated component in React or try to implement the library in react without the component?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have found some components that are not updated with the last React version, however, those components work.  But I was wondering if those components are not updated would be the best option or a good practice to try to implement the libraries in React without the npm packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm my experience, it'll depend upon the product you're working on. IE. you're working in a UI that is not likely changing and once it's done, it'll remain the same for some time (rare case), and it's not too complex. I'd go for the component even if it's not that updated.

If the benefits from constructing the component yourself (long term maintainability, extensibility, etc.) are important to your project and it won't take that much time, maybe it'll be the best option.